# Angular NX - Is It possible to see affected apps without commiting the code or passing list of changed files?

Tags: angular, nrwl, nrwl-nx

One of the most powerful features of NX is to able to see which Angular applications are affected by the recent change.

However, in order to make it work [documentation](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-2) tells that you need:

1. Provide SHA's of two commits: `npm run apps:affected -- SHA1 SHA2` **OR**
2. Specify each file that has been changed and pass them as parameters: `npm run apps:affected -- --files="libs/mylib/index.ts,libs/mylib2/index.ts"`

Obviously, the first option doesn't feet as I don't want to commit my changes and see what's broken. The second option doesn't work as well because it really requires a lot of effort to pass each changed file as a parameter.

Question: is there a way that I can change a file in a lib and see what apps are affected without passing the commit SHA or manually specifying each change? (probably just by analyzing git diff).

Sorry, maybe I misread or missed some documents and somebody can point to the right one. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--uncommitted` option :

`./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:apps --uncommitted`